# Strange undefined method `right_click' error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara, capybara-webkit

I use RoR with cucumber and capybara for tests.

I get strange error whent trying to make right click with capybara:

```
undefined method `right_click' for #<Capybara::Node::Element:0x0000000930c628> (NoMethodError)
```

But that class simply should have right_click method, see http://rubydoc.info/github/jnicklas/capybara/master/Capybara/Node/Element#right_click-instance_method

This is the source code

```
find('a', :text => @name).right_click
```

If I do some mistake, how to simulate right mouse click properly?

Comment: What version of Capybara are you using?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This method is in master only. [Neither of released Capybara versions support it.](https://github.com/jnicklas/capybara/blob/2.2_stable/lib/capybara/node/element.rb)

Comment: @user3024710 if you use Webdriver you can do it via `page.driver.browser.action.context_click(el.native).perform` where `el` is Capybara element.